# Form button 1 should be created after deleting the form button 1

Tags: vba, excel

I'm using form buttons in excel,
When I add form buttons they are added with name `Button 1, Button 2, Button 3`......
Once I clear the sheet and delete all the buttons and when I add them again I want `Button 1` to be created instead of `Button 4`.
Is that possible? If so how to achieve it?
Thanks in advance

Code I used to create button

```
ActiveSheet.Buttons.Add( _
    ActiveCell.Left, _
    ActiveCell.Top, _
    ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Range("A1:C2").Width, _
    ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Range("A1:A3").Height)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you use this, it will give you some functionality into naming the button more dynamically.  However, since you are using ActiveCell to place it, that will cause some problems with them all overlapping if you try to create them all at once.  If you could elaborate as to where the buttons are placed, if they are the same, or what determines their position, I could give more detail.

```
Dim lCount As Long

lCount = 1

Set newButton = ActiveSheet.Buttons.Add( _
    ActiveCell.Left, _
    ActiveCell.Top, _
    ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Range("A1:C2").Width, _
    ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Range("A1:A3").Height)
With newButton
    .Name = "Button" & lCount    'The actual button name.  
    .Caption = newButton.Name    'This is the DISPLAY on the button. 
End With
```

An alternative for that is to leave out the lCount and just name the button in the code.  This would involve you activating the cell you want, and then running the code, and changing the value from 1 to 2, 3, etc, in the .Name property.

```
With newButton
    .Name = "Button1"            'The actual button name.  
    .Caption = newButton.Name    'This is the DISPLAY on the button. 
End With
```

You could have a hidden sheet ("HiddenHelper" in example) that keeps track of how many buttons you've created and have lCount refer to that cell.  When you clear the sheet, you reset that value as well back to 1.  Then when you add another button, have the code add 1 to the cell value keeping track of how many you've used like this:

```
Dim lCount As Long

lCount = Sheets("HiddenHelper").Range("A1") 

Set newButton = ActiveSheet.Buttons.Add( _
    ActiveCell.Left, _
    ActiveCell.Top, _
    ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Range("A1:C2").Width, _
    ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Range("A1:A3").Height)
With newButton
    .Name = "Button" & lCount    'The actual button name.  
    .Caption = newButton.Name    'This is the DISPLAY on the button. 
End With

Sheets("HiddenHelper").Range("A1") = Sheets("HiddenHelper").Range("A1") + 1
```

Of course, you can name the helper sheet whatever you like and set the range for the button count to whatever suits you.